# Efficiency of SQL query that performs joins using temporal/spatial bounds

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL (v. 12.14) and PostGIS to model GPS tracks that pass through "areas". I've created a materialized view that maintains an array of areas-passed-through per track, and the update performance is godawful. I'm trying to understand how the (fairly naive) query works, and how I can improve it.

Here are the relevant parts of the schema:

```sql
create table track (
    start timestamp,
    end timestamp,
    user text
)

create table gps_point (
    create_time timestamp,
    point geometry(point, 4326),
    user text
)

create table area (
    name text,
    polygon geometry(polygon, 4326)
)
```

Note there are no foreign keys between these tables -- I did not create this schema, and would have at least added a foreign key from `gps_point` to `track`.

The guts of the view are generated as:

```sql
select track.start, track.end, array_agg(distinct area.name)
  from track
    join gps_point on (gps_point.create_time between track.start and track.end
                       and gps_point.user = track.user)
    join area on st_covers(area.polygon, gps_point.point)
  group by track.start, track.end
```

So effectively I'm using a temporal `between` to achieve one half of the join, and a spatial `st_covers` to do the other half.

This is ungodly slow (I have indexes on basically all the columns shown above except for `area.name`). In principle I understand that the query is piling up far, far more rows than it needs (hence the `distinct area.name`), and that there might be a way to "short circuit": there's an enormous amount of data in the `gps_point` table, but all I need is a single ping within an area to know that it should be included. That feels like an "EXISTS", but I can't figure out how to get an "EXISTS" in there.

Here's the output of `explain analyze`, obviously the outer nested loop is where the whole thing is falling apart, but I don't know what work that represents:

```sql
 GroupAggregate  (cost=28495760.61..28768028.29 rows=3768 width=108) (actual time=51901.377..53247.436 rows=3055 loops=1)
   Group Key: track.user, track.start, track.end
   ->  Sort  (cost=28495760.61..28550204.73 rows=21777646 width=80) (actual time=51900.803..52624.699 rows=689231 loops=1)
         Sort Key: track.user, track.start, track.end
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 63488kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..22938476.09 rows=21777646 width=80) (actual time=17.638..48055.263 rows=689231 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..8420387.25 rows=46063701 width=72) (actual time=7.599..36250.753 rows=843071 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on area  (cost=0.00..6.75 rows=75 width=135) (actual time=0.028..0.892 rows=109 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using point_idx on gps_point g  (cost=0.41..112267.42 rows=432 width=100) (actual time=3.387..320.934 rows=7735 loops=109)
                           Index Cond: (point @ area.polygon)
                           Filter: st_covers(area.polygon, point)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 2048
               ->  Index Scan using track_user_start_idx on golfround gr  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=843071)
                     Index Cond: (((user)::text = (g.user)::text) AND (start <= g.create_time))
                     Filter: (g.create_time <= end)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning Time: 12.674 ms
 Execution Time: 53259.611 ms
```

Lastly, some statistics about the tables:

```
Rows in track table: 4427
Average GPS points per track: 1000
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: Your query is reading the entire table `track`, joining each row with multiple rows of the table `gps_point` and then joining this cross product with the table `area`. It's bound to be slow. Do you really want to read the entire database each time? Maybe you can include a `WHERE` clause to narrow down the search.

Comment: This is creating a materialized view, so the whole point is to have the data available for `WHERE` searches by other queries. The issue is that refreshing it is so slow that I essentially can't do it every time I would want to, which is after the creation of a new `track`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. A few questions: 1) How many rows does `track` have? 2) In average, how many matching rows (percentage over the whole table) are in `gps_point` for each track? 3) In average, how many matching rows (percentage over the whole table) are there in `area` for each `gps_point`?

Comment: Please update your question with the detailed EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: I've added the explain output, and some statistics. I tried to generate average GPS points per area, starting with this as a base query: `select area.name, count(g.point) as "points" from area join gps_points g on st_covers(area.polygon, g.point) group by area.name`, and it took so long to return that I killed it. So I guess that narrows the culprit down! Simply using `st_covers` to do a join hoses performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make use of an EXISTS subquery, you would need to do a cross join between track and area.  That sounds like a pretty horrible idea, but in this case I would say it is actually worth a try.

```
select track.start, track.end, area.name
  from track cross join area
  where exists (select 1 from gps_point 
      where gps_point.create_time between track.start and track.end
      and gps_point.user = track.user
      and  st_covers(area.polygon, gps_point.point)
  )
```

This could be supported by a multi-column GiST index, something like:

```
create index on gps_point using gist (point, "user", create_time)
```

Where you probably need the btree_gist extension to include the scalar types into the index.  It also isn't obvious which order of columns in the index would be optimal, you could try different orders and see which one works best.

Comment: This looks like a good idea. It's is not a cross join really, because you inner join the tables on the exists clause actually, but it seems to be exactly what is being asked.

Comment: Really interesting! My first naive try (without fooling with indexes) was as slow or slower than my original, but I will spend some time today experimenting with index configurations. Regardless, your query structure is exactly what I was looking for (even if it doesn't end up being an improvement!) so I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks to all.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I think every row in the hypothetical cross join has to go kick the index on gps_point (even if many/most of them end up finding zero rows).  So I think I would still call it a cross join.  But given the low number of areas, it might be viable to do it this way.

Comment: No worries, I was just saying that when we join two tables and use whatever criteria to decide which rows to join, we call this an inner join. To the DBMS it makes no difference if you use `CROSS JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause or an `INNER JOIN` and an `ON` clause. Both are eventually the same inner join and the DBMS should come up with exactly the same execution plan. So use what you find more readable. :-)